# Passively search for Bluetooth devices for location detection

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am building a project (using Arduino) that should detect a person going inside a building (e.g her house, office, etc) and inform a server about it. This should be done seamlessly and handless.

I though of using Bluetooth to do so, because I know that some devices (like a car speaker) can automatically connect to my phone.

Generally, I wish that once the device is in range (using small range BT devices of <1 meter range) my application will be aware of it and can inform the server about it, even if the the phone is "locked" (screen is black). It is possible that the BT device will actively search for the phone and will try to connect to it (assuming the phone and the device) are already paired.

Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do with BT, and if so, how? If not, is there any other way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible but normal bluetooth would consume too much energy as you would constantly have to search for devices. Your use case is typically implemented with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) - for example the famous Apple iBeacon.

Comment: Will BLE work with a normal phone? How does it different from "normal" BT?

Comment: BLE is compatible with newer Android phones (since 4.3). IOS supports iBeacons.

Comment: And is it possible to constantly search for a devices, even when the phone is locked ?

Comment: Yes and no. You can search when the phone is locked but you can't do this constantly. Anything that you do wireless consumes battery and scanning via bluetooth as well. BLE consumes less energy than classical bluetooth but it is also not made for constant scanning. See here for example:   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html  It sounds like your use case could also be implemented with NFC if the range is not too wide (e.g. a door).